# How to get the result of a for loop to print as a 0 instead of integer(0)

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a for loop that goes through a database and returns the elements I need into a vector, but some of the elements return as "integer(0)", is there a way to initially print them as "0" instead of 'integer(0)'

I have tried to switch the integer(0) to NA, but no luck.

```r
ageStart = c()
for(i in CancerMet) {      

  x <- dbGetQuery(conn, paste('SELECT * FROM table WHERE Person = ', i, ';'))

  info = fromJSON(x$info)

  indx <- as.data.frame(info$dx)

  inrx <- as.data.frame(info$rx)

  beforedata <- indx[indx[,1]==4591,]

   start <- head(beforedata[,2],1)

  print(start)

  **startAge <- c(startAge, capture.output(start))**
}
ageEventStarts <- as.data.frame(startAge)
```

Now, I get a vector that has some Integer(0) outputs but I want to replace the integer(0) outputs in the vector to 0. To get a vector of only numerical information. The portion with ** is where integer(0) outputs show up.

Comment: Please highlight the place in your code which is generating the `integer(0)` data.  Also, try to avoid ever using `SELECT *` and instead always list out the columns you want to select.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen could you clarify on how to list columns instead of using SELECT*, thanks.

Comment: `integer(0)` is not a value of `0`, it's an empty vector, so you probably have problems beyond just the way things are printed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, a check for `length` of `beforedata` will be helpful

```
for(i in CancerMet) {      
   x <- dbGetQuery(conn, paste('SELECT * FROM table WHERE Person = ', i, ';'))
  info = fromJSON(x$info)
  indx <- as.data.frame(info$dx)
  inrx <- as.data.frame(info$rx)
  beforedata <- indx[indx[,1]==4591,]
  if (length(beforedata) > 0)
     start <- head(beforedata[,2],1)
  else
     start <- 0
  print(start)
  startAge <- c(startAge, capture.output(start))
}

ageEventStarts <- as.data.frame(startAge)
```